# coffeescript date issue when submitting year as 0001

Tags: javascript

I'm facing an issue in javascript while submitting date. If I submit a date with year as 0001 or 0798 js is converting it into 1, 789.how can i submit date with year as 0001 or 0789 or whatever year I give?.

In firebug console you can try this to see.

Ex: d = new Date

```
Sun Jan 26 2014 18:35:49 GMT+0530 (IST)
d.setFullYear(0001)
-62133389650691
d
Fri Jan 26 1 18:35:49 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Please help me.

Comment: Edited my post and tagged with javascript also..What can I do to accomplish that?

Comment: It may help to [read ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) in regard to Date objects and how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The year of a date is not a string, it's a *number*.

The string returned by `Date#toString` is not (curiously) specified by the specification. It can be whatever the engine wants it to be. Some engines (such as V8 in Chrome) output just as much of the year as is required, so `1` or `789` or `2014` or `12487`. There's nothing special about years that makes them four digits long, after all; it just happens that we live during the 9,000-year period (1000 -> 9999) during which years in our Western calendar (Gregorian calendar, specifically) have four digits.

If you want a string in a particular format (other than the near-ISO format the ES5 spec added via `toISOString`, on engines that support it), you have to format it yourself (or use an add-on library like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com) or similar to do so).

Comment: But here i need a date object not a string.string means i can do it.So  no simple way to do that?

Comment: @user2986573: See the first line of the answer: The year is a *number*, not a string. Numbers are exactly that. The value you're giving the engine is `1` or `789`. Adding zeros to the front is a *formatting* (text-based, e.g. string) concept. So if your goal is to have a `Date` instance with its year set to `1` or `789`, you've achieved that already. (In fact, the year number isn't even stored in the date object, it figures out the year number from the value it holds, which is a milliseconds offset value from midnight Jan 1 1970 GMT [a number which is negative for years prior to 1970].)